# Internationalize element with inner <span>

Tags: spring, spring-boot, internationalization, thymeleaf, properties-file

I'm working with Spring Boot + Thymeleaf. I want to internationalize something like this:

```
<p>Already registered? <span class="link">Log In</span></p>
```

If I add `th:text="#{prompt}"` to the `<p>` tag, the inner `span` will be replaced by the property value.

Is there any way to internationalize the whole **text** of `<p>` element with just one property in my resource bundle? (maybe with placeholders or I don't know)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add placeholders for the html tags inside the property value

Property:

```
prompt = Already registered? {0}Log In{1};
```

Html:

```
<p th:utext="#{prompt('<span class=link>', '</span>')}"></p>
```

Note: I am using `th:utext` instead of `th:text` because it doesn't escape html.

But it would be clearer if you would just have two different properties. E.g.:

```
<p>
    <th:block th:text='#{prompt1}'></th:block>
    <span class='link' th:text='#{prompt2}'></span>
</p>
```

Comment: Are you sure `('<span class=link>', '</span>')` should be after `}`?